# cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/value permission denied [get the gpio status via php]

Tags: raspbian, gpio, php, apache-httpd

I am trying to get the status of gpio17 via php like that:

(Installed: Raspbian, Apache2, PHP5)
This is what i do:

```
echo "17" > /sys/class/gpio/export

echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/direction

echo "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/value
```

After setting the gpio i call the 'gpio_test.php' file in the browser.
This is the gpio_test.php file:

```
<?php
trim(@shell_exec("cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/value"));  
?>
```

When I look into my apache2 log file it says:

> "cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/value permission denied"

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: You need root access to access the gpios. You either have to use sudo (not advisable for a webserver) or change the permissions. See e.g. http://www.raspberrypi.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=8999

Comment: hm didn't work..

Comment: How are you exporting the gpio17?

Comment: Have a look at the post again, i have updated it

Comment: It is simpler to use `/usr/local/bin/gpio export 17 out` but the code you have listed should do the same. I can't see why it doesn't work. It would be interesting to see the result of `ls -la /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/`

Comment: total 0
drwxrwx--- 3 root gpio    0 Feb  7 15:39 .
drwxrwx--- 4 root gpio    0 Feb  7 15:39 ..
-rwxrwx--- 1 root gpio 4096 Feb  7 15:39 active_low
-rwxrwx--- 1 root gpio 4096 Feb  7 15:39 direction
-rwxrwx--- 1 root gpio 4096 Feb  7 15:39 edge
drwxrwx--- 2 root gpio    0 Feb  7 15:39 power
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root gpio    0 Feb  7 15:39 subsystem -> ../../../../class/gpio
-rwxrwx--- 1 root gpio 4096 Feb  7 15:39 uevent
-rwxrwx--- 1 root gpio 4096 Feb  7 15:39 value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output you posted explains why it is not working. 
`edge` and `value` are both owned by `root`

If you run `/usr/local/bin/gpio export 17 out` they should be owned by your user (probably `pi`).
NOTE do not run as `sudo`

I am not sure if `/usr/local/bin/gpio` normally has SUID permission, but if not you can set it with

`sudo chmod u+s /usr/local/bin/gpio`

Comment: Thank you. I have installed raspbian again and used wiringpi which works fine. But your answer is correct :)